# sensor_msgs/Image data value is a string?

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs#image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've written a node in python to read a binary image (of type sensor_msgs/Image) being published on a topic. I got confused when trying to access the data in the callback.

```
print img
```

produces

```
header: 
  seq: 35232
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: ''
height: 40
width: 127
encoding: 8UC3
is_bigendian: 0
step: 381
data: [0, 0, 0, 0, ...]
```

I shortened the data array with an ellipsis.

What's weird are the types of the data.

```
print type(img.data), type(img.data[0])
```

produces

```
<type 'str'> <type 'str'>
```

When I try to display the data with "print img.data" I get a bunch of junk characters. When I try to index into the first element, I get an empty string.

This confuses me because the [description of the topic type Image](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) specifies that the img.data field is an array of bytes. Why am I seeing a string here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59827/sensor_msgs/image-data-value-is-a-string?/) by [robzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3420/robzz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [msg](http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg#Fields) documentation, rospy automatically interprets byte arrays (`uint8[]`) as `strings`.

See this [cv_bridge](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython) tutorial for an example of how to convert image data from a ROS message (byte array) to a "real" IplImage for further processing.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1